# Optional number of wildcards in URL patterns in Django

Tags: python, django, url-pattern

```
#views.py
def sum(*args):
    return reduce((lambda x, y: int(x)+int(y)), args)
```

Is it possible to write one URL pattern that will handle uniformly such requests as /sum/1/2 (result = 3), /sum/1/2/3 (result = 6), etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not exactly what you want, but you could use

```
(r'^sum/(?P<allargs>[/0-9]+)$', 'views.sum')
```

and then

```
def sum(request, allargs):
    args = map( int, allargs.split('/') )
    # Compute sum
```

Comment: This can be extended to handle other data types.  Sort of.  The `[/0-9]+` can be made more elaborate and the `map( int, ... )` would have to be changed, also. But there could be exceptions raised by the conversion `map` function.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you absolutely want to use the form "/1/2/3", you'd rather use query string "/sum?1&2&3". It will be much simpler to implement.